# Is there a URL for generating Microsoft Tags for Windows Phone 7 Apps?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, microsoft-tag

I'm developing a web site that will feature windows phone 7 apps, and I'd like to include a Microsoft Tag so users can point their phone at the screen and download the app that is featured.

So far their website has proven to be quite unhelpful, and it seems you need to sign up for the API if you don't want to generate them all manually.

I was wondering if there is a single URL that I can place the app ID into, hosted on Microsoft's servers, that will generate the tag for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a tag that redirects the phone browser to the app download site, I would suggest you just create a Microsoft Tag account and create the tag as a "one off": Hardcode the url in the tag manager and download the generated tag image. After that you just have to use that image on your website or print advertizement - you don't have to worry about the Tag API or even return to the Tag Manager (as long as your download url stays the same).

Comment: An excellent solution for just a few apps, but this project will most likely need to generate a few tags per week.

Comment: In that case I can only recommend looking into creating a small library for wrapping the Microsoft Tag API: It's really, really easy. :)

Comment: Looks like that what I'm going to do :) Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't just one URL that will create a tag for you.  But this being Stack Overflow, here's a short program that uses the Tag API to create any number of tags.  For the program to work, you will need to:

1. add a service reference to the Tag API at https://ws.tag.microsoft.com/MIBPService.wsdl
2. Make sure to insert your own Tag API key into *creds.AccessToken*.
3. Increase the *maxArrayLength="16384"* value in *app.config* to something higher.  This is needed to pull the ~45KB tag images from the web service.  I used 100000.

The complete blog post is at http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/creating-several-microsoft-tags/.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using MakeTags.Tag;

namespace MakeTags {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            MIBPContractClient tagService = new MIBPContractClient();
            UserCredential creds = new UserCredential();
            creds.AccessToken = "your-access-token-here";

            int tagsToCreate = 10;
            string category = "Main";
            string tagTitlePrefix = "My Sample Tag ";
            string tagImageFilePathFormat = "mytag{0}.png";

            for (int i = 0; i < tagsToCreate; ++i) {
                Console.WriteLine("Creating tag " + i);

                string tagTitle = tagTitlePrefix + i;

                URITag tag = new URITag();
                tag.Title = tagTitle;
                tag.MedFiUrl = "http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/creating-several-microsoft-tags";
                tag.UTCStartDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                tagService.CreateTag(creds, category, tag);

                string tagImageFilePath = string.Format(tagImageFilePathFormat, i);
                byte[] tagImageBytes = tagService.GetBarcode(
                    creds,
                    category,
                    tagTitle,
                    ImageTypes.png,
                    1f,
                    DecorationType.HCCBRP_DECORATION_DOWNLOAD,
                    false);
                File.WriteAllBytes(tagImageFilePath, tagImageBytes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen these pages:

- http://tag.microsoft.com/create-your-own-tag.aspx
- http://tag.microsoft.com/create-your-own-tag-business.aspx

Comment: Yeah unfortunately, It lets you sign up for the tag manager and API. I was hoping there was something more generic. 

eg. http://microsoft.com/tags/wp7/render?id=[insert id here]